# Remove unnecessary parentheses

Tags: code-golf, parsing

You are given a string composed with the characters `0123456789+*()`. You can assume that string is always a valid mathematical expression.

Your task is to remove the unnecessary parentheses, assuming multiplication has higher priority than addition.

The parentheses should be removed only when they are not needed *structurally*:

- because of multiplication higher priority: `3+(4*5)` => `3+4*5`
- because of multiplication or addition associativity: `3*(4*5)` => `3*4*5`
- when they are redundant around an expression: `3*((4+5))` => `3*(4+5)`

Parentheses *should be kept* when they could be simplified because of specific number values:

- `1*(2+3)` should not be simplified to `1*2+3`
- `0*(1+0)` should not be simplified to `0*1+0`

Examples:

```
(4*12)+11         ==>    4*12+11
(1+2)*3           ==>    (1+2)*3
3*(4*5)           ==>    3*4*5
((((523))))       ==>    523
(1+1)             ==>    1+1
1*(2*(3+4)*5)*6   ==>    1*2*(3+4)*5*6
1*(2+3)           ==>    1*(2+3)
0*(1+0)           ==>    0*(1+0)


(((2+92+82)*46*70*(24*62)+(94+25))+6)    ==>    (2+92+82)*46*70*24*62+94+25+6
```

Comment: More testcases please?

Comment: Not a trivial task. Somewhat related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67651/parenthesize-an-expression/68089

Comment: `1*(2*(3+4)*5)*6` should be an interesting testcase (which my solution currently fails for).

Comment: There won't be whitespace in the expression, right?

Comment: @orlp no whitespace, only `0123456789+*()`

Comment: Is "unnecessary" defined _structurally_ or on a per-case basis? In other words, are the parentheses unnecessary here? `(2+2)*1`

Comment: @LuisMendo I think it's fair to interpret it in either way

Comment: @anatolyg I don't think that'd be fair, because the approaches for the two would be very different. It would be good if we got some clarification.

Comment: @Sp3000 I've added more details. I should have used variables `[a..z]` rather than numbers...

Comment: Suggest case `1+((2+3)*4)` -> `1+(2+3)*4`, `1*((2+3)*4+(5+6))` -> unchanges

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Mathematica, <s>105</s> <s>97</s> 91 bytes

<sup>*-6 bytes thanks to [Roman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/87058)!*</sup>

```
a=StringReplace;ToString@ToExpression@a[#,{"*"->"**","+"->"~~"}]~a~{" ** "->"*","~~"->"+"}&
```

Replaces `+` and `*` with `~~` (`StringExpression`) and `**` (`NonCommutativeMultiply`) respectively, evaluates it, stringifies it, and replaces the operators back.

Comment: What? Mathematica doesn't have a built-in?

Comment: @EriktheGolfer It basically does; I'm trying to make it *not* evaluate the operators.

Comment: That's why Mathematica is so-advertised and so-expensive... because of the built-ins I think. But, Mathematica hasn't got a change over other languages if the puzzle is tough enough, yet "other languages" don't compete at all here.

Comment: [91 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY3NCsJADIRfZYkgm6Si@9OqiNKLd1Fv4mGRqgW1oj0IpX31GqvOaTLfMLmG8pxdQ5kfQntUc6XbMN@Uj/x2Wmf3Szhks23xvdNtsXzdH9nzmRe3NOx6UQUEgwUQQQT8cU0D9b4JTQWKSHVMkKTiGOp@izO1kq0ypaMapqoC7clYZGMgUqANWyT3sY6ExNilotg6FP1KpjOGtCXt2KMUKflH7Do6IimO/gOWp5YnMu4TGguynhJ5q6eebYzICULdvgE) by using [`StringExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringExpression.html) instead of `Dot`, and removing the `" "->""` clause: `a=StringReplace;ToString@ToExpression@a[#,{"*"->"**","+"->"~~"}]~a~{" ** "->"*","~~"->"+"}&`

Comment: @Roman Thanks! It seems you found another good associative non-commutative unevaluated operator that doesn't combine with numbers.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6) 163 <s>178</s>

**Edit** 15 bytes saved thx @IsmaelMiguel

```js
a=>eval(`s=[]${_=';for(b=0;a!=b;a=b.replace(/'}\\(([^()]*)\\)(?=(.?))/,(x,y,z,p)=>~y.indexOf('+')?-s.push(b[p-1]=='*'|z=='*'?x:y):y))b=a;${_}-\\d+/,x=>s[~x]))b=a`)
```

*Less golfed*

```js
a=>{
  for(s=[],b='';
      a!=b;
      a=b.replace(/\(([^()]*)\)(?=(.?))/,(x,y,z,p)=>y.indexOf('+')<0?y:-s.push(b[p-1]=='*'|z=='*'?x:y)))
    b=a;
  for(b=0;
      a!=b;
      a=b.replace(/-\d+/,x=>s[~x]))
    b=a;
  return a
}
```

**Test**

```js
f=a=>eval(`s=[]${_=';for(b=0;a!=b;a=b.replace(/'}\\(([^()]*)\\)(?=(.?))/,(x,y,z,p)=>~y.indexOf('+')
?-s.push(b[p-1]=='*'|z=='*'?x:y)
:y))b=a;${_}-\\d+/,x=>s[~x]))b=a`)

console.log=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n'

test=`(4*12)+11         ==>    4*12+11
(1+2)*3           ==>    (1+2)*3
3*(4*5)           ==>    3*4*5
((((523))))       ==>    523
(1+1)             ==>    1+1
1*(2*(3+4)*5)*6   ==>    1*2*(3+4)*5*6
1*(2+3)           ==>    1*(2+3)
0*(1+0)           ==>    0*(1+0)
(((2+92+82)*46*70*(24*62)+(94+25))+6)    ==>    (2+92+82)*46*70*24*62+94+25+6`

test.split`\n`.forEach(r=>{
  var t,k,x
  [t,,k]=r.match(/\S+/g)
  x=f(t)
  console.log((x==k?'OK ':'KO ')+t+' -> '+x+(x==k?'':' expected '+k))
})
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Why did you wrote `y.indexOf('+')` instead of ``y.indexOf`+`[...]``? ([...] added to avoid tripping the formatting) Was it bugging out that way?

Comment: Here you go, 170 bytes: ``a=>eval(`for(b=s=[]${_=';a!=b;a=b.replace(/'}\\(([^()]*)\\)(?=(.?))/,(x,y,z,p)=>~y.indexOf('+')<0?-s.push(b[p-1]=='*'|z=='*'?x:y):y))b=a;for(b=0${_}-\\d+/,x=>s[~x]))b=a`)``

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel that's really clever, thanks! Lesson learned: when passing to eval, rethink it all again

Comment: I'm glad you liked my simple solution to reduce your code. I wish I could do something about `for(b=`, `=='*'` and other repeated bits. Also, isn't `~y.indexOf('+')<0` the same as `~y.indexOf('+')`? Since the only value that `indexOf()` returns that evaluates to a falsy value is `-1`, the `<0` seems redundant. Or, if I got it wrong, you could do `y.indexOf('+')>1`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel 1: yes, the `<0` is crap remaining from the ungolfed version and should be removed. 2: thinking again, the `for` can be revised to be included in the repeated part. Thanks again

Comment: Wow, you made a really nice touch! I didn't though about it! I wish I could upvote again... But nice work on chopping off those bytes!

Comment: @Oliver: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8428/avoid-useless-edit-about-byte-count

Answer (score 5):

## Python3 + [PEG implementation in Python](https://gist.github.com/orlp/363a4261f6a884311cbbe6a146a3052b), 271 bytes

```
import peg
e=lambda o,m=0:o.choice and str(o)or(m and o[1][1]and"("+e(o[1])+")"or e(o[1]))if hasattr(o,"choice")else o[1]and e(o[0],1)+"".join(str(x[0])+e(x[1],1)for x in o[1])or e(o[0])
print(e(peg.compile_grammar('e=f("+"f)*f=p("*"p)*p="("e")"/[0-9]+').parse(input())))
```

A while back I made a [PEG implementation in Python](https://gist.github.com/orlp/363a4261f6a884311cbbe6a146a3052b). I guess I can use that here.

Parses the expression into a tree, and only keeps parenthesis if the child is addition, and the parent is multiplication.

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, 132 bytes

129 bytes source + 3 for `-p` flag:

```
#!perl -p
0while s!\(([^\(\)]+)\)!$f{++$i}=$1,"_$i"!e;s!_$i!($v=$f{$i})=~/[+]/&&($l.$r)=~/[*]/?"($v)":$v!e
while($l,$i,$r)=/(.?)_(\d+)(.?)/
```

Using:

```
echo "1*(2*(3+4)*5)*6" | perl script.pl
```

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <s>140</s> 130 bytes

127 bytes source + 3 for  `-p` flag:

```ruby
t={}
r=?%
0while$_.gsub!(/\(([^()]+)\)/){t[r+=r]=$1;r}
0while$_.gsub!(/%+/){|m|(s=t[m])[?+]&&($'[0]==?*||$`[/\*$/])??(+s+?):s}
```

And ungolfed:

```ruby
tokens = Hash.new
key = '%'

# convert tokens to token keys in the original string, innermost first
0 while $_.gsub!(/\(([^()]+)\)/) { # find the innermost parenthetical
  key += key # make a unique key for this token
  tokens[key] = $1
  key # replace the parenthetical with the token key in the original string
}

# uncomment to see what's going on here
# require 'pp'
# pp $_
# pp tokens

# convert token keys back to tokens, outermost first
0 while $_.gsub!(/%+/) {|key|
  str = tokens[key]
  if str['+'] and ($'[0]=='*' or $`[/\*$/]) # test if token needs parens
    '(' + str + ')'
  else
    str
  end
}
# -p flag implicity prints $_
```

Comment: very nice answer.  what is happening with the `0 while` syntax?

Comment: @Jonah In Ruby, `expr while cond` is equivalent to `while cond; expr; end`. Here, I only want to perform `cond` repeatedly and don't actually have a loop body. Usually one would write this as `while cond; end` or perhaps `loop{ break unless cond }` but `0 while cond` is fewer bytes. The `0` doesn't do anything; it's just there because the short form of the while loop requires a body.

Answer (score 2):

## Retina, 155 bytes

```
{`\(((\d+|\((((\()|(?<-5>\))|[^()])*(?(5)^))\))(\*(\d+|\((((\()|(?<-10>\))|[^()])*(?(10)^))\)))*)\)
$1
(?<!\*)\((((\()|(?<-3>\))|[^()])*(?(3)^))\)(?!\*)
$1
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=e2BcKCgoXGQrfFwoKCgoXCgpfCg_PC01PlwpKXxbXigpXSkrKD8oNSleKSlcKSkoXCooXGQrfFwoKCgoXCgpfCg_PC0xMD5cKSl8W14oKV0pKyg_KDEwKV4pKVwpKSkqKVwpCiQxCig_PCFcKilcKCgoKFwoKXwoPzwtMz5cKSl8W14oKV0pKyg_KDMpXikpXCkoPyFcKikKJDE&input=KDEqKDIrMykrNCkqNQ)

[Verify all testcases at once.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JXtgXCgoKFxkK3xcKCgoKFwoKXwoPzwtNT5cKSl8W14oKV0pKyg_KDUpXikpXCkpKFwqKFxkK3xcKCgoKFwoKXwoPzwtMTA-XCkpfFteKCldKSsoPygxMCleKSlcKSkpKilcKQokMQooPzwhXCopXCgoKChcKCl8KD88LTM-XCkpfFteKCldKSsoPygzKV4pKVwpKD8hXCopCiQx&input=KDQqMTIpKzExCigxKzIpKjMKMyooNCo1KQooKCgoNTIzKSkpKQooKDErMikpKzMKKDErMSkKKCgoMis5Mis4MikqNDYqNzAqKDI0KjYyKSsoOTQrMjUpKSs2KQoxKigyKigzKzQpKjUpKjYKKDEqKDIrMykrNCkqNQ&debug=on)

#### Explanation

The main thing is this code:

```
(((\()|(?<-3>\))|[^()])*(?(3)^)
```

This regex can match any string in which the brackets are balanced, e.g. `1+(2+(3))+4` or `2+3`.

For the ease of explanation, let this regex be `B`.

Also, let us use `<` and `>` instead for the brackets, as well as `p` and `m` for `\+` and `\*`.

The code becomes:

```
{`<((\d+|<B>)(m(\d+|<B>))*)>
$1
(?<!m)<B>(?!m)
$1
```

The first two lines match for brackets which consist of only multiplication, e.g. `(1*2*3)` or even `(1*(2+3)*4)`. They are replaced by their content inside.

The last two lines match for brackets which are not preceded and which are not followed by multiplication. They are replaced by their content inside.

The initial `` {` `` means "replace until idempotent", meaning that the replacements are done until they either no longer match or they are replaced with themselves.

In this case, the replacements are done until they no longer match.

Comment: Fails for `1*(2*(3+4)*5)*6`.

Comment: @orlp Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Fails for `(1*(2+3)+4)*5`

Comment: @Sp3000 Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>274</s> <s>269</s> <s>359</s> <s>337</s> 336 bytes

This method basically removes every possible pair of parentheses and checks to see if it still evaluates the same.

```py
from re import *
def f(x):
    *n,=sub('\D','',x);x=sub('\d','9',x);v,i,r,l=eval(x),0,lambda d,a,s:d.replace(s,"?",a).replace(s,"",1).replace("?",s),lambda:len(findall('\(',x))
    while i<l():
        j=0
        while j<l():
            h=r(r(x,i,"("),j,")")
            try:
                if eval(h)==v:i=j=-1;x=h;break
            except:0
            j+=1
        i+=1
    return sub('9','%s',x)%tuple(n)
```

**Test Harness**

```py
print(f("(4*12)+11")=="4*12+11")
print(f("(1+2)*3") =="(1+2)*3")
print(f("3*(4*5)")=="3*4*5")
print(f("((((523))))")=="523")
print(f("(1+1)")=="1+1")
print(f("1*(2*(3+4)*5)*6")=="1*2*(3+4)*5*6")
print(f("(((2+92+82)*46*70*(24*62)+(94+25))+6)")=="(2+92+82)*46*70*24*62+94+25+6")
print(f("1*(2+3)")=="1*(2+3)")
print(f("0*(1+0)")=="0*(1+0)")
```

**Updates**

- **-1** [16-10-04] Removed extra space
- **-22** [16-05-07] Made use of the `re` lib
- **+90** [16-05-07] Updated to handle the new test cases
- **-5** [16-05-07] Removed parameter from the length (`l`) lambda

Comment: This fails the test case `1*(2+3)`, because OP said not to simplify for special number cases. Good answer though; this has my upvote.

Comment: @AlexL. Thanks for catching that! I didn't update my test cases D: But it is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP, 358 bytes**

```
function a($a){static$c=[];$d=count($c);while($g=strpos($a,')',$g)){$f=$a;$e=0;for($j=$g;$j;--$j){switch($a[$j]){case')':++$e;break;case'(':--$e;if(!$e)break 2;}}$f[$g++]=$f[$j]=' ';if(eval("return $f;")==eval("return $a;"))$c[str_replace(' ', '', $f)]=1;}if(count($c)>$d){foreach($c as$k=>$v){a($k);}}return$c;}$t=a($argv[1]);krsort($t);echo key($t);
```

Not an impressive length, that's what I get for taking a less than optimal approach (and using a less than optimal language).

Strips a pair of brackets out, then evals the resulting expression. If the result is the same as the original it adds it to a map of valid expressions and recurses until no new expressions can be found. Then prints the shortest valid expression.

Breaks when the result of the expression gets large and casts to double / exponent notation show up.

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>122</s> 118 bytes

```
T+S:-term_string(T,S).
I/O:-X+I,X-Y,Y+O.
E-O:-E=A+(B+C),A+B+C-O;E=A*(B*C),A*B*C-O;E=..[P,A,B],A-X,B-Y,O=..[P,X,Y];E=O.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9Pa4NAEMXP8VOIp92dXZNd/7SxtEWLh5wsTQ5KkBCKDYFEw2qwJ7@6HRMIFN3LLL/35vHmoqtTdRB1e@z7DawD0RT6vKsbfSwPZMPX1DZW8yQQKax4KjKeQWIbsUASv4ZAIvigPAQcInlBwkjEBsJw3Ihtbz95yKOchyLlESYkd5byLEc9sXt9LXff@7og8e9FUzMQxmz4zb@K@npquDH7qfR53xCra03xZnZtV3alxbeDid9NOdY03oX5iLKIy6SiIKWF0n9FgqLMGXGH4Y5Hx358nnIovqksOaaSEcWIAy7FPOZP6uCM9xYM8xaTDRQsFTxjb9dnT@hTLvPxPLJ0QXmUgk@n74RbDdT6Pw)

Defines a predicate `//2` which removes parentheses from its first argument's string value and outputs a string through its second argument. If input could be in Prolog terms, this would only be <s>81</s> 77 bytes defining `+/2` without having to deal with the verbose `term_string/2`, but a lot of unnecessary parentheses would simply not have existed to begin with that way so it would be pretty close to cheating, since all that `+/2` does is handle associativity.

I tried to use `=../2` for all of it, but it came out far longer, because a three-byte operator that works with lists isn't exactly terse:

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 124 bytes

```
T+S:-term_string(T,S).
I/O:-X+I,X-Y,Y+O.
X-Y:-X=..[O,A,B],(B=..[O,C,D],E=..[O,A,C],F=..[O,E,D],F-Y;A-C,B-D,Y=..[O,C,D]);X=Y.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU9Na4NQEDzHXyGe3sc@E58fbQxpicZATkKTgxIkhGJDINGgBnvyr9u10paie5qdmR1m70V@zc@irC9tu@c7V1RpcTuWVXHJzmQPO6or22noiohvIRIxxDzUFQTILHX9EMIKvASI1y8@rBMIfgQ/gU2Pg47fiHixEj54Yg3xn58uomWst8UjO76fypQEn/eCqq5QJh2avqXl41qBMvnIi9upIlpTq@JFbeomazINDp0JelOCZZVXof5GacRihqTcMDSU/isGl5SZA95keGPToR/HlibFGcsyhqzBiGTE5BbFPOaM6twc3s0Y5s1GG0g@l/wZe1sOe0KftJiD75G5xaVNKXfo@J/8uwZq7Rc)